# After applying SUPEE-6788 can't create customer

Tags: customer, supee-6788, form-key

After installing the patch, customers are unable to register accounts.

Comment: Check customer/form/register.phtml template. The form should contain a form key now (XSS protection)

Comment: Check files mentioned by James and check the patch file line numbers 4392 & 4331 (If patch is for Magento 1.7.0.2)

Answer (score 21):

The patch adds a new form key to

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
```

and to

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
```

If your theme overrides these, simply add -

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

right after this line -

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
```

Comment: similar I added <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and this solution saved my day!

Go to:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
```

and

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
```

Add this line of code:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

after

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
```

If the problem still exist check the template you are using then go to 
`app/design/frontend/default/[YOUR TEMPLATE]/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml` simply add the same code above
after that dont forget to clear cache.